# Replace column in csv with modified column

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I got a csv file with a couple of columns and a header containing 4 rows. The first column contains the timestamp. Unfortunately it also gives milliseconds, but whenever those are at 00, they are not given in the file. It looks like that:

```
"TOA5","CR1000","CR1000","E9048"
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","BattV_Avg","PTemp_C_Avg"
"TS","RN","Volts","Deg C"
"","","Avg","Avg"
"2015-08-28 12:40:23.51",1,12.91,32.13
"2015-08-28 12:50:43.23",2,12.9,32.34
"2015-08-28 13:12:22",3,12.91,32.54
```

As I don't need the milliseconds, I want to get rid of those, as this makes further calculations containing time a bit complicated. My approach so far:

Extract first 20 digits in each row to get a format such as `2015-08-28 12:40:23`

```
timestamp = []
with open(filepath) as f:
    for _ in xrange(4): #skip 4 header rows
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        time = line[1:20] #Get values for the current line
        timestamp.append(time) #Add values to list
```

From here on I'm struggling on how to procede further. I want to exchange the first column in the csv file with the newly created `timestamp` list.

I tried creating a dictionary, but I don't know how to use the header caption in row 2 as the key:

```
d = {}
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for col in csv_reader:
        #use header info from row 2 as key here
```

This would import the whole csv file into a dict and I'd then change the TIMESTAMP entry in the dict with the `timestamp` list above. Is this even possible?

Or is there an easier approach on how to just change the first column in the csv with my new list so that my csv file in the end contains the timestamp just without the millisecond information?

So the first column in my csv should look like this:

```
"TOA5"
"TIMESTAMP"
"TS"
""
2015-08-28 12:40:23
2015-08-28 12:50:43
2015-08-28 13:12:22
```

Comment: can you show what the file looks like? Especially the header info from row 2 you are trying to get.

Comment: Also would advice to add what you want the csv to look like after your operation.

Comment: I edited the initial post that now contains this information

Comment: Is the `1` / `2` also present in the file? And are the headers all quoted like that in the file itself? I would adivce you to directly copy paste the starting few lines of the csv here.

Comment: updated the initial post. No enumeration in the file, sorry. But yes, the quotes are there. This is how it actually looks like now (there are 30 more columns though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it and preserve the quoting:

```
with open(filepath1, 'rb') as fin, open(filepath2, 'wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for _ in xrange(4):  # copy first 4 header rows
        writer.writerow(next(reader))
    for row in reader:  # process data lines
        row[0] = row[0][:19] # strip fractional seconds from first column
        writer.writerow([row[0], int(row[1])] + map(float, row[2:]))
```

Since a `csv.reader` returns the columns of each row as a list of strings, it's necessary to convert any which contain numeric values into their actual `int` or `float` numeric value before they're written out to prevent them from being quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can easily create a new csv from iterating over the original csv and replacing the timestamp as you want.

Example -

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csv_file, open('<new file>','wb') as outfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):    #Enumerating as we only need to change rows after 3rd index.
        if i <= 3:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            csv_writer.writerow([row[0][1:20]] + row[1:])
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant. I would have never thought about that! One more issue though: in my newly created file all quotation marks are erased. Any idea why? This could be a problem when replacing this file with the machine output that's accessing this file.

Comment: Do you want all fields to be quoted? If so when openning the `csv.writer` you can add an extra argument `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about how to parse your csv but I would do something of the sort:

```
time = time.split(".")[0]
```

so if it does have a millisecond it would get removed and if it doesn't nothing will happen.